# Converting hash ruby objects to positive currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, currency

I have a hash where the keys are the months and I want to convert the objects to positive numbers AND currency.

INPUT

```
hash = {
  12 => -5888.969999999999,
  4 => -6346.1,
  3 => -6081.76,
  2 => -5774.799999999999,
  1 => -4454.38
}
```

OUTPUT

```
hash = {
    12 => 5888.96,
    4 => 6346.10,
    3 => 6081.76,
    2 => 5774.79,
    1 => 4454.38
}

#Output should be a float
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: expected output please

Comment: Your output is invalid syntax - are the values strings or BigDecimals or what?

Comment: Numeric.abs() can be applied to ensure a number is positive and Float.round(2) will round a float to 2 decimal places.  See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Numeric.html#method-i-abs and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Float.html#method-i-round for usage examples.

Comment: So the abs method worked but I cant use float because some of the objects have 1 digit after decimal already and that throws an error

Comment: I updated the question for the output to be a float

Comment: @TrisNefzger That got it, with a little manipulation. Post an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @SupremeA - round() does not add trailing zeros since that does not affect numerical value. There is a trick of multiplying the number by 100 before rounding it and dividing by 100 afterwards when using plain round() with no precision argument - which still does not add trailing zeros. However, for printouts the number can be formatted to have a certain number of digits after the decimal point and which will be filled in with trailing zeros as needed. An example of how to do that is in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric.abs() can be applied to ensure a number is positive and Float.round(2) will round a float to 2 decimal places. See ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Numeric.html#method-i-abs and ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Float.html#method-i-round for usage examples. Note that round() will not add trailing zeros since that does not affect numerical value, however trailing zeros can be added by formatting, for example:

```
hash = {
  12 => -5888.969999999999,
  4 => -6346.1,
  3 => -6081.76,
  2 => -5774.799999999999,
  1 => -4454.38
}

# transform hash values
hash.each do |key, value|
  hash[key] = value.abs().round(2)
end

# print the modified hash without formatting the values
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} => #{value}"
end

# prints 
# 12 => 5888.97
# 4 => 6346.1
# 3 => 6081.76
# 2 => 5774.80
# 1 => 4454.38

# print hash with values formatted with precision of 2 digits
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} => #{'%.2f' % value}"
end

# prints
# 12 => 5888.97
# 4 => 6346.10
# 3 => 6081.76
# 2 => 5774.80
# 1 => 4454.38
```

Comment: I am finding that `.round(2)` still can have an output such as `84.0`.  June 5 2018, `Ruby 2.5.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
hash.transform_values{|v| v.round(2).abs()}
```

or

```
hash.update(hash){|k,v| v.round(2).abs()}
```

Comment: 'An error' is unhelpful to people who are trying to help diagnose -- what is the error.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `transform_values' for #<Hash:0x54ce4f27> Bcs transform_values is ROR method so if you dont use ROR you must find another solution